# Getting stackoverflow exception while inserting images in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have a view pages inside it there are fragments with gridview and images(Emojis) inside gridview. it's like an activity with emojis and you can swipe between different emoji types.
This is my viewpager activity

```
SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
Fragment[] fragments = {SmileysFragment.newInstance(0)};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.emoji_layout);
    slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tab_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    initViews();
}

private void initViews() {
    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }
    };
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    List<DataHolder> dataHolders = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; ++i) {
        dataHolders.add(new DataHolder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selected), "我", getResources().getColor(R.color.md_material_blue_600)));
    }
    slidingTabLayout.setUpViewPager(viewPager, dataHolders);
}
```

This is my Fragment activity

```
 public class SmileysFragment extends Fragment {


GridView grid;
public static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";

int[] image_ids = new int[]{
        R.drawable.s1,
        R.drawable.s2,
        R.drawable.s3,
        R.drawable.s4,
        R.drawable.s5,
        R.drawable.s6,
        R.drawable.s6,
        R.drawable.s6,
        R.drawable.s6,
        R.drawable.s6,
        R.drawable.s6

};


public static SmileysFragment newInstance(int i) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(KEY_INDEX, i);
    SmileysFragment fragment = new SmileysFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    if (container == null) {
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.smiley_emoji_layout,container,false);
      grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.smileyGridview);
        SmileysAdapter adapter = new SmileysAdapter(getActivity(),      image_ids);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        view = container;
    }
    return view;
}
```

This is my adapter class

```
public class SmileysAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;
private int[] image_ids;
public SmileysAdapter(Context c,  int[] resources) {
    mContext = c;
    image_ids = resources;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_ids.length;
}



@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return image_ids[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    if (convertView == null) {

        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smiley_item_layout, null);


    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.smiley_item);

    imageView.setImageResource(image_ids[position]);
    return grid;
}
```

This is the exception I am getting

```
02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : FATAL EXCEPTION: main

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : java.lang.StackOverflowError

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at      android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5355)

 02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at   android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

 02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)
```

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

```
02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

02:07:11 E AndroidRuntime : at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5359)

 02:07:11 W ActivityManager : Force finishing activity com.example.app/.EmojiActivity
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong

Comment: Also  provide the exception stack trace from logcat

Comment: @AndroidMechanic done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `onCreateView()` is messed up.

It should look like this:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.smiley_emoji_layout, container, false);
        grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.smileyGridview);
        SmileysAdapter adapter = new SmileysAdapter(getActivity(), image_ids);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
```

I think you got confused with adapter's `getView()`.  When a fragment creates its view, there is no recycling involved.  The container will never be null.  You should always return a view you have inflated, and never return the container itself.